# FRSdiag.exe install by an end user?

Tags: replication, diagnostic

Why would an end user (non-admin, but knowledgable) attempt (but fail) to install FRSdiag.exe on their workstation?  Is there a security issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to ask the user why they did it. I don't see an inherent security issue, but it would depend on what they were trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the function of the file I would guess he was told it will be able to do something for him? Possible he is trying to find a solution for a problem, possibly backing up his files to take home or keeping backups generally?

(Please note I am just randomly guessing)

Answer (score 0):

I'd ask them, but take some precautions - It could have been something innocent wondering how to fix a problem, but it could have been a rogue employee trying to gain access to more information about the network than they need. I can't think of a way they would actually gain anything useful doing this alone though.